# Writing macro in Excel to remove HTML TAG

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write to a macro which remove html tags from excel data.
I just want search for <*> this pattern and replace them with blank. 
Also need to remove special characters like '“'and tags like if(typeof(dstb)!= "undefined"){ dstb();}.

Code I have written till now requires me to hardcode files name in macro , which I do not want.

code :

```
 Sub UnescapeCharacters()
 sheetname = "2011 Publications" 'file name goes here

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Me.Worksheets(sheetname)

For Row = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Column = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = sheet.Cells(Row, Column)


        ReplaceCharacter cell, "&quot;", """" 
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "&#44;", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "&nbsp;", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "&bull;", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</ul>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<ul>", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<b>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</b>", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<i>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</i>", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</li>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<li>", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</br>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<br />", ""

        ReplaceCharacter cell, "</p>", ""
        ReplaceCharacter cell, "<p>", ""

    Next Column
Next Row

End Sub

Sub ReplaceCharacter(ByRef cell As Range, ByVal find As String, ByVal replacement As     String)

Dim result As String
cell.Value = Replace(cell.Text, find, replacement, 1, -1)

End Sub
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: How about tags with attributes, like `<div style="color: #ChuckNorris;">` - And is "It is < 5 and > 3" an HTML tag?

Comment: I do have tags like  <div style="color: #ChuckNorris;"> .

Comment: `Code I have written till now requires me to hardcode files name in macro , which I do not want.` -> what is it that you do want? To chose file at run-time? A loop through specific filenames?

Comment: It should take name of the file on which it is currently running.

Comment: Is it the file name, or the sheetname?

Comment: There is the possibility of using RegExp in VBA which would greatly help though I am not knowledgeable enough in that matter to know if it is possible to only scan for HTML tags and not fall into the pitfall @MikeChristensen described.

Comment: http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/2011/12/strip-html-how-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string-in-vba/

Comment: ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Comment: Mentioning regex + HTML inevitably leads us to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/53614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer doing it in this approach. 
If the HTML is NOT a real website, you can save the HTML as a file, then IE.navigate that filePath.

```
   Sub testing()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim stringWithOutTags As String
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ' HardCode the URL address in
        IE.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824872/writing-macro-in-excel-to-remove-html-code"
        Do While IE.Busy
        Loop
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4
        Loop


        stringWithOutTags = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerText

        IE.Quit
    End Sub
```